# Call of system(...) to process file created by curl_easy_perform fails randomly?

Tags: c++, curl

I am using libcurl to get some archive file from an URL and write it to disk with a simple C++ wrapper that does nothing but `curl_easy_setopt` into `curl_easy_perform`.
This call is immediately followed by

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
system("bash -c 'unpack \"path_to_archive\"'");
```

Where bash is on Windows 10 in cygwin, but not sure if this is relevant. I have been using this for a while and it works, but only *almost* always.. Sometimes, the `unpack` will fail and print an error, but the even more curious thing is that if I then go to the directory myself, and manually call `unpack` from a terminal on the same file written by curl, it works.

So there is no write error, and as far as I can tell, I did not suppress any errors in the code. In my wrapper I have

```
if(curl_easy_perform(handle)) throw std::runtime_error("CURL error")
```

which never throws. I could only imagine a few causes:

- The code leaves `curl_easy_perform` before it actually finishes writing the file (it is supposed to be synchronous..?). This makes `unpack` fail on an incomplete file, but shortly after the write is completed
- Similar, but somehow the write to disk, which may have some asychronous low level calls (it really shouldn't ..?), does not "finalize" the file properly (whatever that would mean?) before the call to `unpack`
- ???

I am stuck here because it only fails rarely. I did some tests with larger files to try and reproduce the error more frequently, but it did not seem to make any difference. So it is hard to test as each run takes very long and I have no better guesses than the two above..
For the first guess writing larger files should have made a difference, and in the second I have no idea how to try and fix it aside from inserting an even longer sleep than there already is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Writing to a file may be synchronous in your code, but be asynchronous at the OS layer.  It make take some extra time for the data to actually flush from OS caches to the disk, unless you flush the file manually.

Comment: So my second guess was on the right path. Thanks, I will try to find out how I could flush manually, unless someone can help *edit* wait.. I'm passing an ostream .. so I should be able to just flush that! Guess I will find out in the next however many hours of runtime if this happens again or not.

Comment: Flushing an `ostream` just writes any buffered data from memory to the storage media (ie, to a file for an `ofstream`), but that doesn't necessarily mean the OS will then flush its caches to disk at the same time. I'm thinking something more like you needing to call `FlushFileBuffers()` on Windows, or `fsync()` on Posix systems, after closing the `ostream`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I see, thanks for the pointer, I'm not familiar at all how this is handled by the OS. Would have been nice if std::filesystem provided a platform independent way for this, but I don't see any.